# Salesforce: Adding items to 'Personal Setup' and 'Customize'

Tags: salesforce

I am writing a simple salesforce app that requires app-level and user-level configuration. I have created custom objects for these settings, but cannot figure out how to add links to the Setup page (Personal Setup and Customize) so that the settings can be managed.

Quite a lot of research, and a question on a salesforce board, have left me none the wiser. I have seen a couple of scripts on the web that hack the setup sidebar with javascript (eg http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/95361) ... but this can't be the right way to do it surely?

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to do this without hacking because Salesforce want it so that you don't require over-explicit setup of any app you create - they want you to make it data-independent and in fact it may fail a security review if it is data dependent. It will also likely cause you headaches in correctly unit testing the app.

My suggestion would be to have a set of custom pages which are linked to on the home page for a user which display if they have no current values (so the first thing they see on the home page when they login for the first time is a "Hey, before you use this app you need to do some configuration through this handy wizard" and then block access to other areas of the app (i.e. display warning messages on other pages) if the app has not had this data setup.

That way you are not hacking and are providing a nice user experience around the extra setup.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

DO you just want to add a new TAB on the top menu that links to the Edit page for your new sObject?

If so:

1. Goto setup  https://cs3.salesforce.com/ui/setup/Setup
2. Click on 'Create' > 'Tab'
3. Pick the sObject you want the tab edit, the click next until you save the new tab.

Comment: Daveo, I have created a new tab, and that's fine, it works. But what I would like to do is add a link under 'Setup -> App Setup -> Customize', to that tab, or a visualforce page that delivers a similar UI.

Comment: You cannot edit the left hand menu of the standard Salesforce interface.  HOwver you can just edit the Tabs. You can create a tab for your own custom VF page.  Or make your on VisualForce page(s) that have there  own menu structure

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to augment the Setup menu.

You should probably be using Custom Settings for what you are describing - they were designed for app-level and user-level configuration, and are available from Setup.

Otherwise, if it really is custom setup that requires fancier logic / UI / etc, you may want to do what many SFDC ISV's do and ship your app with its own configuration tab that's hidden, and/or custom VF page that manages app settings.